# _mappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(urlLeftPart) explained

Tags: dxa, web8.5

What's the logic behind `_mappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(urlLeftPart)` in `CdApiLocalizationResolver`? Our issue is some Pages which have been published appear 404 in front end. After we debug the code, we found they are mapping to wrong Publication

Comment: Are the mappings correct in Topology Manager? I assume this code is just checking what publication ID maps to the current URL being request.

Comment: I checked the mapping using powershell script. they are correct. those pages sometimes display fine. sometimes shows 404 error.

Comment: What did you check using PowerShell, exactly? Did you use the CD Publication Mappings API directly (the same one as DXA is using)?

Comment: I checked by using getTtmMapping command. Can you advise how to use CD Publication Mappings API? @RickPannekoek